# Autolayout horizontal alignment for label unless another item encroaches

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a custom navigation bar (simple UIView at the top of the controller) which has two objects, a label which describes the screen and a button on the right side.

I wish to make the label horizontally (center) aligned **when possible**.  When the screen size is too small (4" iPhone for example), I would like the label to move to the left to allow both items to fully show and have the text not truncated.

This is the way it should look when space allows:

[image: This is the way it should look when space allows:]

Small device, not ideal:

[image: Small device, not ideal:]

How I would like it too look on small devices:

[image: How I would like it too look on small devices:]

Does anyone know if this is possible with AutoLayout?

Comment: Doesn't the navigation bar do that for you anyway, with the title moving to make space for the bar button items?

Comment: Using a custom navigation bar, i.e. a UIView.

Comment: OK, I assume you have a good reason for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with Auto layout :

Give both of your title : `Content Compression Resistance priority` of `1000`.

Your left title should have `Center Horizontally constraint` with priority `<1000`. (Give it `750`).

Give them `Horizontal spacing constraint` in between them and other constraint as well.

Comment: the horizontal spacing constraint should be >= your minimum spacing rather than a fixed value

Comment: I thought that I tried that, but I guess not.  Works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also create optional constraints. All constraints have a priority between 1 and 1000. Constraints with a priority of 1000 are required. All other constraints are optional.

You can create one constraint with priority 1000 and one with 750.

When calculating solutions, Auto Layout attempts to satisfy all the constraints in priority order from highest to lowest. If it cannot satisfy an optional constraint, that constraint is skipped and it continues on to the next constraint.

Even if an optional constraint cannot be satisfied, it can still influence the layout. If there is any ambiguity in the layout after skipping the constraint, the system selects the solution that comes closest to the constraint. In this way, unsatisfied optional constraints act as a force pulling views towards them.

Check apple documentation here [Constraint Priorities](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW9).